# java null pointer exception when trying to get path  of an image

Tags: android

I am working on a contact list project and the last thing i need to do is display images for each of my contact.
In code from below i want to show my image by using the path wich is saved in my edittext1:
but i get NUll pointer exception on this  line:

```
 String username = mpic.getText().toString(); 



        private void ShowImage()
  {
      //string username created from edit text field to a string
      EditText mpic =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
      String username = mpic.getText().toString(); 
        //bitmap will decode the string to a image (bitmap)
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(username);
        //Image view used to set the bitmap
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        //setting the image to the image view
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

  }
```

The whole class is :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main); 
     ShowImage();
      showDatabaseContent();
      lv1 = getListView();

      lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

       lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
           cursor = (Cursor) a.getItemAtPosition(position);
           itemId = cursor.getString(6);
           openOptionsMenu();
           }
       });

       lv1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

       });
   }

   //selected item index from ListView
   public void showDialogItemId(long itemId){
       Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected index is" + Long.toString(itemId), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
       switch (item.getItemId()){
           case R.id.modifyitem:
               if(null != itemId){
                   Bundle contactToModify = new Bundle();
                   contactToModify.putString("cFirstName", cursor.getString(0));
                   contactToModify.putString("cMobilePhone", cursor.getString(5));
                   contactToModify.putString("cEmail", cursor.getString(2));
                   contactToModify.putString("curl", cursor.getString(3));
                   contactToModify.putString("cAdress", cursor.getString(4));
                  contactToModify.putString ("cphoto", cursor.getString(1));
                   contactToModify.putString("mod_type", "modifyPerson");
                   Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactDetails.class);
                   intent.setClass(this, ContactDetails.class);
                   intent.putExtras(contactToModify);
                   startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_MODIFIED);
               }else{
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Select Contact to modify", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               break;
           case R.id.additem:

               Intent i = new Intent(this, ContactDetails.class);
               Bundle bun = new Bundle();
               bun.putString("mod_type", "addPerson");
               i.setClass(this, ContactDetails.class);
               i.putExtras(bun);
               startActivityForResult(i, CONTACT_ADDED);
               break;

           case R.id.removeitem:
               if(null != itemId){
                   removeContact(itemId);
                   showDatabaseContent();
               }
               else{
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Select Contact to delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               break;
           case R.id.search:
               Intent j =new Intent(this,Search.class);
               j.setClass(this, Search.class);
               startActivity(j);
                break;

       }
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
       // See which child activity is calling us back.
       switch (resultCode) {
           case CONTACT_ADDED:
               // This is the standard resultCode that is sent back if the
               // activity crashed or didn't doesn't supply an explicit result.
               if (resultCode == RESULT_FIRST_USER){
                   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                   bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("contactData");
                   addContact(bundle);
                   showDatabaseContent();
               } 
               else{
                   Toast.makeText(this, "CANCEL CONTACT BUTTON PRESSED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               break;
           case CONTACT_MODIFIED:
               if (resultCode == 2){
                   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                   bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("contactData");
                   modifyContact(bundle);
                   showDatabaseContent();
               }
               else{
                   Toast.makeText(this, "MODIFY CONTACT FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               break;
           default:
               break;
       }
   }

 //method removes item from database
   private void removeContact(String itemId){
       db = contacts.getWritableDatabase();
       db.delete(DbConstants.TABLE_NAME, "_ID=" + itemId, null);

   }

   private void addContact(Bundle bundle) {
          // Insert a new record into the Events data source.
          // You would do something similar for delete and update.
          db = contacts.getWritableDatabase();
          ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
          vals.put(DbConstants.NAME, bundle.getString("contactFirstName"));
          vals.put(DbConstants.PHONE, bundle.getString("contactMobilePhone"));
          vals.put(DbConstants.EMAIL, bundle.getString("contactEmail"));
          vals.put(DbConstants.URL_STRING,bundle.getString("contactUrl"));
          vals.put(DbConstants.ADRESS,bundle.getString("contactadress"));
          vals.put(DbConstants.PHOTO,bundle.getString("contactphoto"));
          db.insertOrThrow(DbConstants.TABLE_NAME, null, vals);
       }

 //method should modify existing Contact
   private void modifyContact(Bundle bundle){
       db = contacts.getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
       vals.put(DbConstants.NAME, bundle.getString("contactFirstName"));
       vals.put(DbConstants.PHONE, bundle.getString("contactMobilePhone"));
       vals.put(DbConstants.EMAIL, bundle.getString("contactEmail"));
       vals.put(DbConstants.URL_STRING,bundle.getString("contactUrl"));
    vals.put(DbConstants.ADRESS,bundle.getString("contactadress"));
    vals.put(DbConstants.PHOTO,bundle.getString("contactphoto"));
       db.update(DbConstants.TABLE_NAME, vals, _ID+"="+itemId, null);
   }

   private Cursor getContacts() {
          db = contacts.getReadableDatabase();
          cursor = db.query(DbConstants.TABLE_NAME, FROM, null, null, null,
                null, null);
          startManagingCursor(cursor);
          return cursor;
   }

   public void showDatabaseContent(){
       contacts = new DbCreate(this); 
       try {
           cursor = getContacts(); 
           showContacts(cursor); 
       } finally {
           contacts.close();
           db.close();

       }
   }


   private void showContacts(Cursor cursor) {
       //set up data binding
       SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, FROM, TO);
       setListAdapter(adapter);
   }
  private void ShowImage()
  {
      //string username created from edit text field to a string
      EditText mpic =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
      String username = mpic.getText().toString(); 
        //bitmap will decode the string to a image (bitmap)
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(username);
        //Image view used to set the bitmap
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        //setting the image to the image view
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

  }
```

Whole error:

```
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.dbcontactconsole/org.example.dbcontactconsole.DbContactConsole}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at org.example.dbcontactconsole.DbContactConsole.ShowImage(DbContactConsole.java:234)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at org.example.dbcontactconsole.DbContactConsole.onCreate(DbContactConsole.java:46)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post the full exception, including stack trace.

Comment: Are you sure there is text in the EditText?

Comment: Sounds like `mpic` is null. Are you sure that `R.id.edittext1` is the id of a view in the Activity's layout?

Comment: When i dont call method show image its show me on screen The name of the contact and the path of image wich is saved in "edittext1" because this is implemented in show contacts method.maybe the error  appears beacuse i cal show contact() method and show image () at the same time in on create

Comment: @DourHighArch - actually posting the stack trace, while perhaps customary, was not necessary, as all it reveals is the location of the null pointer exception, which was already stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely possibility is that mpic is null because no view could be found by that id.

A secondary possibility is that the result of calling the .getText() method on mpic is null, so that calling the toString() method on the result fails.

You should add an explicit check to verify that the objects are not null before you try to call their methods, or else surround the attempt with a try/catch, and do something informative if you detect a problem.

You can also use the android logging facility to print a representation of the objects to the logs, and manually check which is null - though that won't help you with a future problem that might only arise due to some condition occurring on an end-user's device but not on your development/test devices.